# Configure POP3 Connector for SBS 2008 (Exchange 2007)

Tags: exchange-2007, windows-sbs-2008

I have a client which has all his mail on server outside of his company. Right now his exchange server (on SBS 2008 is configured using POP3 connector but problem is mail gets deleted from server when downloaded by connector. Is there a way to make pop3 connector leave emails on server (external one) and download them as well for use within Exchange.

Client wants to "feel" exchange before making the move totally so he would like to play with it for longer while without loosing mails he has on his server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The POP3 pull in SBS has no setting to leave messages on the server as Outlook provides in email polling.

You can however setup Outlook to pull with POP3 and store the email into your Exchange profile (local OST).  This way you can test Exchange while leaving email on the mail server for later.  The only issue is, you need to configure each Outlook separately.

Comment: It's an old topic and my client doesn't have his SBS anymore but it's an answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

I feel that is an option when the user sets up the account.

Here are my directions

Account Settings > New Account > Internet E-Mail > Check Manually configure and click next.
Type in your settings and click the "More Settings" button. Then click the "Advanced" tab.

The last section in there is "Delivery".

Check the "Leave a copy of the messages on the server and make sure the Remove options are NOT checked.

This should do it!

Comment: You mean Outlook internal settings and not Exchange 2007 server.... It's not what it is about.

Comment: Yah in Outlook internal settings.
Check it. Its not clicked by default.

Comment: Campo your solution is for different scenario. It's not client issue but more like a on server (SBS2008/Exchange 2007) setting that I'm looking for. Have a read what I'm talking about http://blogs.technet.com/sbs/archive/2009/07/01/sbs-2008-introducing-the-pop3-connector.aspx

Comment: AHH! I see. Yah SBS... Must be a setting in there that is similar to the client side one. I have never used a SBS 2008 server so I cannot help further.